# Cache mechanism for Large scale application

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have working on spring boot and postgresql technologies.currently i have implemented in memory cache.but i have need to scale the data access of application.what is the best solution?if we are using third party cache ,what is the best technology we can use?

I have tried redis.but I don't know which version of client we can choose.

Answer (score 0):

For using Redis with Spring Boot, you typically use a Redis client library. The "Lettuce" and "Jedis" libraries are two commonly used Redis client libraries for Java.

To use Lettuce in your Spring Boot project, you can include it as a dependency in your pom.xml or build.gradle file

To use Jedis in your Spring Boot project, you can include it as a dependency

Choose the version that is compatible with your Spring Boot version and satisfies your project requirements.